# Numbers unable to be added into a List

Tags: c#

I am trying to store the elements that are given in the main function into the list from textinput class and echo it out. The numeric input class is to filter the elements that are being stored to be of numeric values only. I want the output to be just 10 as the purpose of numeric input class is to filter out the letter 'a'. However, I got some errors such as end of file expected and missing "{" and "}". I checked if i had missed out some of these but i couldn't find any missing ones. Also, am I doing this right because I am new to the language and I need some advice on how to correct and improve it. Thank You.

EDIT: I have edited my code with the feedbacks that I have gotten and some new error messages appeared. Errors such as:-

> The name 'add_char' does not exist in the current context.
>
> The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found.
>
> 'TextInput' does not contain a definition for 'c' and no extension method 'c' accepting a first argument of type 'TextInput' could be found

EDIT2: So after importing the System.Collections.Generic and changing the list to protected, I encountered other errors as shown in the screenshot:-
[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG4Xq.png)

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TextInput {   
    
   protected List<char> add_char = new List<char>();

   public void Add(char c){
        
        add_char.Add(c);
        
    }

    public string GetValue(){    
        
        for (add_char.size = 0; add_char.size < 400; add_char.size++)
            {
               return  c;                
            }
                       
    }

}

public class NumericInput:TextInput{

    public new void Add(char c){

        if(char.IsNumber(c)){ 
            
            add_char.Add(c);
        
        }else{

            Console.WriteLine("This is not a number");

        }

    }

}

public class UserInput
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextInput input = new NumericInput();
        input.Add('1');
        input.Add('a');
        input.Add('0');
        Console.WriteLine(input.GetValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: The code will not compile -) `extends` is not available in C# instead you can use `:`

Comment: I am requesting you to explain the question well. There are still better ways to do this :)

Comment: I have gotten into some error after making modifications to the code. I edited the post and have written out the new error messages. Thanks

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic to avoid <The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found.>

Answer (score 1):

This line prevents it from being added to list as char is never is a int (char and int are different types):

```
if(GetValue(this.c).GetType() == typeof(int)){
```

instead change it to:

```
if(char.IsNumber(c)){ add_char.Add(c);}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The name 'add_char' does not exist in the current context.

Because it doesn't.  `add_char` is a local variable declared in the `Add` method of your `TextInput` class.  Local variables can only be used in the method scope in which they're declared.  You're trying to use it in a different method (the `Add` method of your `NumericInput` class).  Perhaps you meant to declare it at the class level in `TextInput`?:

```
protected List<char> add_char = new List<char>();

public void Add(char c)
{
    //...
}
```

> The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found.

Add `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of the file.  Note also that Visual Studio helps you with this.  If you place your cursor or hover your mouse in the use of `List<>` then a tooltip should show (with a little light bulb) to help correct the error.

> 'TextInput' does not contain a definition for 'c' and no extension method 'c' accepting a first argument of type 'TextInput' could be found

Because it doesn't.  `c` is a local variable declared in the `Add` method of your `TextInput` class.  Local variables can only be used in the method scope in which they're declared.  When someone calls `GetValue()`, what exactly are you wanting to return?  That method has no variables.  With the above change you can move `add_char` to the class level, then that method can access it.

Comment: So are you saying that the Add method should be converted into a class inside the textinput class? Also after implementing the using  System.Collections.Generic;  and making the list protected, a list of errors is showing instead.

Comment: @lol: *"So are you saying that the Add method should be converted into a class"* - Not at all.  As for the new errors, you're trying to use the `protected` keyword inside a method which is throwing off the parsing.  To make something a class-level member, it needs to be declared in the class instead of in a method, just as demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: So i've made the add_char list to a class-level, but it shows the same error message where the textinput class does not contain a definition for 'c' for my getValue method. Am i returning it wrongly?

Comment: @lol: Because your `GetValue` method doesn't have a variable called `c`.  It doesn't have any variable.  Take a step back for a moment.  Instead of randomly moving code around until something compiles, define what you logically want your methods to do.  Conceptually, what should `GetValue` return?

Comment: So inside textinput class, the add method adding a value into a list and getValue method returning the current value, while inside the numeric input class, the add method is to override the add method in the textinput class to filter out char type values and only stores numeric values into the list. This is the flow of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @lol: What is "the current value"?  The most recent thing added to the list?  Something like `add_char.Last()`?  If you're `using System.Linq;` that is.  Otherwise I suppose `add_char(add_char.Count - 1)` would work just as well.  In both cases you'll also want to check if `add_char` is empty and either return a default value or throw an exception.

Comment: Hmm how about i do it in another way, where i apply the loop into the get Value method. The loop will determine the prevent the size of the list from going over 400, and it will return c. Whereas the add method will be just a normal add_char.Add(c), thus adding the c into the list. Is this way of doing correct?